# jquery store array localstorage or cookie

Tags: jquery, arrays, cookies, store, local

I want to store an array in order to use it after a refresh page browser or with history forward (if my website is in the history).

This array is very important for me because it contains all my history urls of my visited website pages. It allows me to detect back and forward browser buttons.

for example I've got `history_url_array = [];`, how can I store it in local or in cookie easly and compatible with html4 and html5 without plugin script?

I success to do this kind of thing but just with a variable like this : `self.name= window.location.pathname;`

Sorry for my English, I'm French...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set an array (in your case `history_url_array`)  in `localStorage`, use

```
localStorage["history"] = JSON.stringify(history_url_array)
```

On page refresh, to get your array back from `localStorage`,

```
var history = JSON.parse(localStorage["history"])
```

But mind the browser support. IE has been shaky in its support for HTML 5 components. Here's the support table :

[image]

Anyway its better to run this function before you start using `localStorage`.

```
function supports_html5_storage() {
  try {
    return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

If this function returns `true` you can insert your `[]` in `localStorage`, else, you'll have to store in a database or server session storage.

For more info on `localStorage`, head over to [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Comment: thank you for your answer. So it will not work in HTML4 browsers if I correctly understand?

Comment: @freaky pls look at the support table ive added now. this is where LS is supported

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's enought browser support for me to use it! Don't care about others user...